# Add days to a date over years in increments

Tags: javascript, .net, date, extjs, coffeescript

i Want to add days to a date and then increment that date over a time span. i Have the same time span issue lock down but i am having a issue with trying to make the date increment properly i know that getDate() + 7  is wrong and i would not like to use a plugin. Any Ideas? the main issue is if the dates over lap a year it will always take the current year and iam guessin that is because of how i instantiate the date.  If what i am asking is not clear I can answer your questions.

```
var last, packEndDate, packStartDate;

while (i < frequencyValue) {
  packStartDate = new Date();
  packEndDate = new Date();
  debugger;
  if (isWeek) {
    packStartDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (7 * i));
    packEndDate.setDate(packStartDate.getDate() + 7);
  } else {
    packStartDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (30 * i));
    packEndDate.setDate(packStartDate.getDate() + 30);
  }
  last = frequencyValue - 1;
  if (i === last) {
    packEndDate = endDate;
  }
}
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified my code so it looks like this.

```
                  packagesToAdd = []
                  packStartDate = new Date()
                  packEndDate = new Date()
                  while i < frequencyValue
                       if isWeek
                           toIncrementWeekly = 7 * i
                           offset = toIncrementWeekly * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                           packStartDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + offset)
                           packEndDate.setDate(packStartDate.getDate() + 7)
                       else
                           toIncrementMonthly = 30 * i
                           offset = toIncrementMonthly* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                           packStartDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + offset)
                           packEndDate.setDate(packStartDate.getDate() + 30)

                       last = frequencyValue - 1
                       if i == last
                              packEndDate = endDate
                       number = ('0' + i).slice(-2)
                       i++
```

Work Amazing. Thank you dmlittle

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Date objects based on the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Since the number of milliseconds in a minute, hour, day, week are set we can add a fixed amount to the current time in order to get a time in the future. We can forget about what day of the month, or year it is as it's inherent in the number of milliseconds that have passed since 1970.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the loop, but if you want to increment a particular day by a certain number of days you can do the following:

```
var numberOfDaysToIncrement = 7;
var offset = numberOfDaysToIncrement * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var date = new Date();
var dateIncremented = new Date(date.getTime() + offset);
```

Comment: Works well used this in the end.

Answer (score 1):

use extjs

use add method in Ext.Date object. reference: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-add

eg: Ext.Date.add(new Date('10/29/2006'), Ext.Date.DAY, 5);

Comment: it is very easy. it will take some time to adopt to it. use api docs well.